# i want to use li tag in div but this is not recommended is there any other way?

Tags: asp.net, html

```
<div class="Port"> 
    <li class="FieldList"><asp:Label CssClass="label" ID="Label4" runat="server"></asp:Label></li>
    <li class="FieldList"><asp:Label CssClass="label" ID="Label19" runat="server"></asp:Label></li>
    <li class="FieldList"><asp:Label CssClass="label" ID="Label20" runat="server"></asp:Label></li>
</div>
```

but use of li inside div shows warninig-- Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Element 'li' cannot be nested within element 'div'.  please give any suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about wrapping the `li`s in a `ul`

```
<div class="Port"> 
  <ul>
    <li class="FieldList"><asp:Label CssClass="label" ID="Label4" runat="server"></asp:Label></li>
    <li class="FieldList"><asp:Label CssClass="label" ID="Label19" runat="server"></asp:Label></li>
    <li class="FieldList"><asp:Label CssClass="label" ID="Label20" runat="server"></asp:Label></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

this way the `li`s are still nested in a div but now valid